# 'Multichannel' linear model

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling

I have a linear model which is given as

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} &= A\mathbf{s} + \mathbf{H}{\bf\unicode[Times]{x3b8}} \\
           &= [\mathbf{s} ~ \mathbf{H}][A ~ {\bf\unicode[Times]{x3b8}}^{\rm{T}}]^{\rm{T}} \\
           &= [\mathbf{s} ~ \mathbf{H}]\tilde{{\bf\unicode[Times]{x3b8}}}
\end{align}
$$

The result is a vector. If $\mathbf{H} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}$, ${\bf\unicode[Times]{x3b8}} \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times 1}$ and $\mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$, $\mathbf{x} \ \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

Now in my work, I want to formulate a multichannel linear model. This means that I have $L$ channels such that

$$
\mathbf{x}{_{l}} = A\mathbf{s}{_{l}} + \mathbf{H}{\bf\unicode[Times]{x3b8}}_{l}
$$

If the term $\mathbf{s}$ was similar for all channels (i.e. $\mathbf{s}_{1} = \mathbf{s}_{2} = \cdots = \mathbf{s}_{L} = \mathbf{s}$) then it is simple to write the multichannel linear model

$$
\mathbf{X} = [\mathbf{s} ~ \mathbf{H}]\tilde{{\bf\Theta}}
$$

where

$$\tilde{{\bf\Theta}} = \begin{bmatrix} A & A & \cdots & A \\ {\bf\unicode[Times]{x3b8}}_{1} & {\bf\unicode[Times]{x3b8}}_{2} & \cdots & {\bf\unicode[Times]{x3b8}}_{L} \end{bmatrix}$$

Knowing that each ${\mathbf{s}}_{l}$ is different, how can I write the multichannel linear model?

I need to know this in order to evaluate the model for use in a maximum likelihood estimator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some work, I found one way.

Suppose $\tilde{\mathbf{H}}_{l}$ to be $[\mathbf{s}_{l} ~ \mathbf{H}]$, and $\mathbf{e}_{l} = [0 \cdots 1 \cdots 0]^{\rm{T}}$ with the $1$ at the $l$-th position (i.e. the unit vector for dimension $l$).

A way to write the multichannel linear model is

$$
\mathbf{X} = \sum^{L}_{l=1} \tilde{\mathbf{H}}_{l} \tilde{\bf\unicode[Times]{x3b8}}_{l} \mathbf{e}_{l}^{\rm{T}}
$$

If all $\mathbf{s}_{l}$ are similar, then the expression becomes the simple multichannel linear model in the original question post.